# data type and size for "embed code" in MySql?

Tags: mysql, database, embedding

I'm building a website where users will be allowed to embed code (for Instagram photos, Youtube videos, etc.). They will be allowed to embed an unlimited number of such embeds.

The website is built using MySQL, PHP, Javascript, HTML, CSS.

What would be an appropriate data type and size for storing the embed code in the MySQL database?

I'm wary of making the size too large lest some web-bot starts pasting large amounts of gibberish text and bloats my database size.

Comment: By "code" do you mean hyperlink?

Comment: You know how you can embed a YouTube video on any blog? There's some embed code you have to copy and paste from the original video (that you are embedding). That code is what I mean.